# Marking cards as 'not for trade' in Pokemon TCG Online

Tags: pokemon-tcg-online

In the Pokemon Trading Card Game Online, when creating a trade request, the "I am Giving" option will by default only give you a list of cards currently marked as "for trade". In order to view all cards that are not trade-locked, one has to modify the filters.

When browsing open trade requests from other players, if I have no filter applied (apart from 'acceptable trades only'), results will display for all the trades I could fulfil based on all the cards I own that are not trade-locked. It appears as if the for-trade property is not factored in.

There are some cards I own - such as Tapu Lele-GX and Gardevoir-GX - that I own and are not trade-locked but seem to be in very high demand. Any time I search open requests, a majority of results will involve players asking for these cards. My question is; can cards be somehow labelled as 'not for trading', or can a filter be applied to only show acceptable trades with cards marked as 'for trade'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do is to filter by trades where they want something you have for trade or create an insane trade for your valuable cards and leave it up for as long as possible.

Users have been asking them to implement this for **years**, lmao.

Comment: I thought it might have been something I was overlooking in the filters, but it's at least good to know the feature is not there at all. Next time they ask for feedback, I'll join the queue to pitch this : ) .